# EF Code First Migrations, how to avoid breaking production site when testing dev code on production data?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

For my app development when I want to push something to production, my testing goes like this: test dev code on dev db --> test dev code on production db --> publish dev code to production site --> dev code is now prod code.

I've been using EF Code First Migrations and it's awesome, but it causes some problems with this workflow. If you try and run any of your dev code against the production db and it contains any changes to models within the dbcontext. With custom written or automatic migrations, it will apply those changes and change the DB. This breaks the production site because suddenly it's db doesn't match when it expects in the DbContext model.

Is there a way to avoid this? Can I disable that EF check? Or is there a smoother way? I've also seem you can supply null to the DBInitializer, but this doesn't create a _MigrationHistory table then. Are there implications to set it to null only when publishing to production, but otherwise have it set to migrations?

Certainly if I remove a property on an object in the context, any references to that property or query I would expect those pages to break on production (no different than using plain old SQL Connections), but not the entire production site.

I imagine I would want some toggable option like disabling the model check and I would set that true only when publishing to production. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not have an SSIS package that copies prod data to a test DB?

Comment: That would seriously impact performance, we are a small shop and our hardware isn't super great, when can that run and how long would it take? Also often times I am making changes for new data was just put in and we need modifications based on that, so I couldn't wait for that to run or run it ad hoc during standard hours. I could only copy what I need to test, but now my scope of work is expanding and my process began more complex. It seems easier to just disable this EF feature. If I just used SQL Connections, it would work fine. Doing all this work to work around EF seems bad.

Comment: If you don't apply migrations your model and the database will be different.  It doesn't matter if you use EF or anything else: if your code expect something to be in the database, and it isn't it should fail. Don't blame EF. if, for example your migration adds a new column that's needed by a new functionality in your application, do you really expect it to work with a database that doesn't have that column? Please, deletes or reword your question. Excuse me for my rudeness, but this question is absurd.

Comment: I'm completely aware of how EF Migrations works and I fully acknowledge it wouldn't work in my original post, read more carefully. The issue is I am okay with having any pages that use the changed entity not work on production, I am not okay with the ENTIRE SITE not working because one entity used on one page is now changed. If I was using SQL COnnections, I could do that and only have that one page break.

Answer (score 2):

You must have individual enviroments of Development and Production, and also individual databases of Development and Production, but your database of Development must be always the most possible up-to-date with production DB data. There is no sense you to test Dev code on production DB, because your application need that your database be exactly the same as your models. I recommend you to use a stagging enviroment remotely, for those kind of things, like [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/), you can instantly deploy and scale .NET applications on the Cloud, hosted in IIS, and test with remote Database too, more like your Production enviroment, i believe.

Comment: @DOTang what you think ?

Comment: Someone said the exact same thing in the comments and I outlined why it's not really feasible in my environment. The main concerns being 1) Our resources are not that heavy, to do a full copy of production to db would really bog down our db server because we have a lot of data. 2) This copy, if it happened, would have to be done early in the morning, but often times I need to implement a new feature because of new data, that same day. So that complicates matters more. 3) Working around these problems adds more complexity and extra requirements to our process. Which seems silly.

Comment: Because those increase in requirements are simply to work around how EF works, when if I was using another ORM, or SQL Connections, it wouldn't even be happening.

Comment: @DOTang Dude, if you have a really big amount of data, you could copy, just a part o this, or copy just data to represent a scenario. The big thing here is not concern about future implementations, or if you will change your ORM, and so on, this is just examples that could happen, the most important thing here, is that you are making changes in production DB, this will affect your users, and has great chances to affect the data, that already in the database